# Generate the keys for the ModelState dictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

As far as I understood the ModelState in .NET Core returns a structure like that:

```
{
  "Field1": [ "error1", "error2" ],
  "Field2.NestedField": [ "error1", "error2 ],
  "CollectionField[3]": [ "error1", "error2"]
}
```

Now, if I do some additional custom validation in the controller (e.g. database queries if entities referenced by ids exist) I need to set the key as string.

I just can't figure out how to build the key to get to those formats.
Do this format have a name?

Using name of does give only the name of the field but not the parent fields.

Is there a simple way to generate those names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using name of does give only the name of the field but not the parent fields.

You can concatenate the `nameof`s like so:

```
nameof(MyModelType.EmbeddedObject) + "." + nameof(MyModel.EmbeddedObject.Id)
```

which yields `EmbeddedObject.Id` as `nameof` will always yield the last segment of the expression chain. Simply build the string by digging one level deeper with each expression.

You could alternatively write a LINQ expression helper:

```
public static string GetFullPropertyPath<TModel,TProp>(Expression<Func<TModel,TProp>> expr)
{
    return String.Join(".", GetMemberList(expr.Body as MemberExpression));
}

public static List<string> GetMemberList(MemberExpression expression)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    if (expression.Expression is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        result.AddRange(GetMemberList(memberExpression));
    }

    result.Add(expression.Member.Name);

    return result;
}
```

The `GetMemberList` returns the chain of members selected, without the parameter. So, if you provide an expression such as `m => m.EmbeddedObject.Id` it will return `[ "EmbeddedObject", "Id" ]` which, when joined with `.`s yields `EmbeddedObject.Id`.

The `GetFullPropertyPath` simply returns the list of members in the expression joined with a `.` character. [Here](https://rextester.com/MEMO62096) is an online demo slightly modified as it does not allow the `is MemberExpression memberExpression` syntax.

As a side note, I'd also suggest trying the [FluentValidation library](https://fluentvalidation.net/), which - albeit produces a slightly differently structured validation response - is much more versatile in my opinion than the built-in attribute validation.